# Unit testing for pending intent

Tags: android, android-unit-testing

Any idea on how to write unit test case for the below function:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.flow_nav_graph)
            .setDestination(R.id.UserActicity)
            .setComponentName(UserActivity.class)
            .createPendingIntent();
  
    try {
        context.startIntentSender(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what do you want it to test?